# How to install Gin with Golang

Tags: linux, go, module, webserver, go-gin

I'm a newbie on Golang, and I'm trying to use [Gin](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin) to develop a web server on Ubuntu 16.04.

After executing `go get -u github.com/gin-gonic/gin`, many folders appear at `~/go/pkg/mod/github.com/`.

Then I try to make an example:

```
package main

import "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.GET("/ping", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.JSON(200, gin.H{
            "message": "pong",
        })
    })
    r.Run() // listen and serve on 0.0.0.0:8080 (for windows "localhost:8080")
}
```

However, `go run example.go` made the error:

```
example.go:3:8: cannot find package "github.com/gin-gonic/gin" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin (from $GOROOT)
        /home/zyh/go/src/github.com/gin-gonic/gin (from $GOPATH)
```

In my system, `$GOROOT` is `/usr/local/go/` and `$GOPATH` is `~/go/`.

How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For Go version 1.11 or newer, You should use [Go Modules](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules).

If you are just starting with Go, you should start with the newer version. I think you are using a Go version that supports go modules already because the modules you are trying to get are downloading to `~/go/pkg/mod/` directory.

#### To initialize a project with go module, run:

```
go mod init your-project-name
```

This will create a `go.mod` file in your project directory.

#### Add missing and/or remove unused modules:

```
go mod tidy
```

This will fill up the `go.mod` file with appropriate modules and create a `go.sum` in your project directory. The go.sum contains expected cryptographic hashes of each module version.

After that, the `go run example.go` command should run the program without any issues.

---

#### You can even vendor the modules in your project directory:

```
go mod vendor
```

This will bring all the vendors to your projects `/vendor` directory so that you don't need to get the modules again if working from another machine on this project.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that after adding a package called `gopls`, my IDE is working perfectly.

Install `gopls` using snap: `sudo snap install gopls --classic`

Answer (score -1):

From the error, you can see that GOPATH is your '/home/zyh/go' not your ~/go.
and you can run shell `go env` to confirm where is your GOPATH? then modify it.

Comment: `/home/zyh/go` is `~/go`.